# Do all Stochastic matrix have a stationary probability vector?

Tags: stochastic-processes, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I know that a stochastic matrix will have 1 as one of its eigenvalues.
But do the stochastic matrices all have a stationary probability vector?

Basically, could there be a case where the eigen vector doesn't sum to 1?

Comment: I think this is a consequence of Perron-Frobenius theorem. A stochastic matrix has a positive (each entry is positive) eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $1$. So, dividing by the sum of the entries, you get a probability vector which is also an eigenvector.

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119891/finite-state-markov-chain-stationary-distribution

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Augustin and Bryon.
It seems that:
There can in fact be many eigen vectors for eigenvalue 1 which are not probability vectors.
There can also be many probability vectors (aka stationary probability vectors), for the eigenvalue 1.

thank you for your answers.