# When does the stationary distribution exist for a Markov chain?

Tags: markov-chains

I am trying to find (ideally) an if and only if statement stating the existence of a stationary distribution for a time-discrete, finite state Markov chain.

So far I have only found sufficient conditions involving irreducibility of a Markov chain but not necessary and sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is **always** a stationary distribution for any finite state (time-homogeneous) Markov chain. We normally assume irreducibility to ensure uniqueness, not existence. See [Finite State Markov Chain Stationary Distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119891/finite-state-markov-chain-stationary-distribution).